# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra 'antro'?

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales

Hoy en dia, en México, se dice 'antro' a un club/discoteca o simplemente un bar. ¿De dónde viene la palabra? ¿Cuándo se empezó a usar?

Comment: Solemos decir: un antro de mala muerte - a cualquier lugar (público?) en malas condiciones, o con mal "ambiente".

Comment: en algunos círculos, se usa también en España, aunque suena más a vocabulario de los 80

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Viene](http://rae.es/antro) del latín *antrus*, y este del griego *ἄντρον* caverna. Lo de usarse para indicar un sitio de vida nocturna es un mejicanismo por extensión del significado 2. *m. Local, establecimiento, vivienda, etc., de mal aspecto o reputación.*

Comment: No sé cuál será el origen de la acepción de establecimiento, pero en España se utiliza también exactamente para eso: un bar, pub, discoteca nocturno.

Comment: Yo siempre lo he oído (en España) aplicado con cierto matiz despectivo. Un antro no es cualquier local, sino uno especialmente sucio, cutre o con gente indeseable.

Comment: En México se le llama *antro* a cualquier sitio de vida nocturna, no solo a uno de mala reputación. Por eso escribí ***es un mejicanismo por extensión del significado...***

Comment: @CesarGon: Efectivamente al igual que en España, el antro es un lugar sucio y/o con gente indeseable. La gente joven en México hace como 20 o 25 años aproximadamente empezó a usar esa palabra para referirse a lugares para bailar como una forma graciosa de molestar a los padres de que uno iba a ir a "un antro de vicio y perdición" y se volvió tan común que hoy en día solo dicen "voy al antro" o "voy a ir a un antro" cuando van a ir a bailar o a un bar o, como dice vorbote, a cualquier sitio de vida nocturna.

Comment: @SergioRomero: Entendido. Gracias. ;-)

Comment: @CesarGon: Una definición igual he escuchado en Colombia _"pero creo que está en desuso"_, por lo general escucho con mas frecuencia la palabra _amanecedero_ que tiene connotaciones _similares_ a la palabra _antro_

Answer (score 2):

El diccionario de la Real Academia Española incluye la etimología de todas sus entradas. Un buen truco a recordar para cualquier duda etimológica básica.

http://dle.rae.es/antro

(Del lat. antrum y este del gr. ἄντρον).

En España antro solo se utiliza para aquellos bares de mal aspecto y / o reputación. Normalmente se aplica a bares o restaurantes, no tanto a otro tipo de locales.

Answer (score 1):

En mi época (1978) se denominaba antro a los lugares de mala reputación, y de mala muerte, donde proliferaba la gente de lo peor, llámese ladrones, asesinos, prostitutas y se consumía heroína y drogas. En la actualidad los jovenes la empezaron a usar por el año 1998 cuando se referian despectivamente a alguna discoteca en la cual no los habian tratado con cordialidad, o se habian sobrepasado con copas y los tuvieron que echar de ahi. 
De ahi viene la palabra antro para referirse a lugares elegantes o finos, ya sea karaoke bar, canta bar, discoteca. Y el termino cabaret se lo dejaron a los realmente antros, siendo que en mi epoca los cabaret (palabra proveniente de Francia) era un lugar donde se presentaban espectaculos musicales, bailables comicos etc, y en dode eran recibidos por un portero quine acomodaba los coches y los atendian meseros elegantemente vestidos