# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "garito"?

Tags: etimología, historia

Igual que "antro" ([¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra 'antro'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3148/1674)), "garito" se utiliza mucho para definir un lugar de ocio, normalmente bar, de no muy buena fama pero con buen ambiente.

Por curiosidad he mirado en el DRAE su origen:

> **[garito](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=cL0fgOmrnDXX2yPBe8aa)**
>
> (De garita).
>
> 1. m. Casa clandestina donde juegan los tahúres o fulleros.
> 2. m. Ganancia que se saca de la casa del juego.
> 3. m. Establecimiento de diversión, especialmente el de mala fama.
> 4. m. germ. casa (‖ edificio para habitar).

la sorpresa me ha venido al ver que procede de ["garita"](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=DdhGnUxR2DXX2NM1EmQR):

> 1. f. Torre pequeña de fábrica o de madera fuerte, con ventanillas largas y estrechas, que se coloca en los puntos salientes de las
>      fortificaciones para abrigo y defensa de los centinelas.

por lo que me surge la duda: ¿cómo evolucionó "garita" hasta "garito" para significar algo supuestamente tan diferente? ¿Se entendería que las garitas se convirtieron en lugar de ocio, pecado y diversión?

Comment: Probablemente los centinelas del cuerpo de guardia pasaban el tiempo jugando a las cartas o los dados mientras esperaban su turno. Si encuentro alguna referencia, escribiré una respuesta.

Comment: No recuerdo la referencia, pero tengo entendido que en la historia de algunas palabras se ha usado la diferencia masculino/femenino para marcar diferencias de tamaño. Por ejemplo: _cubo/cuba, puerto/puerta, jarro/jarra, canasto/canasta_, y _barco/barca_. Tal vez se dio el mismo fenómeno entre _garito_ (grande como una casa) y _garita_ ("torre pequeña").

Comment: _solo es curiosidad, pero:_ ¿dónde ha escuchado esta palabra, es originaria de algún país?

Comment: @Mauricio en España, donde se utiliza con frecuencia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tras investigar en Google Books, encontré dos fuentes que hacen derivar *garito* del vascuence. El [*Diccionario trilingüe del castellano, bascuence y latín*](https://books.google.com/books?id=whdf0XXf6gwC&pg=PA390&dq=garito&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=garito&f=false) (1745), de Manuel de Larramendi, dice:

> Garito, la casa de el juego, es voz Bascongada de el mismo origen de
>   garita

y en *Garita* dice:

> Garita, de soldado, es voz Bascongada, que se sincopó de *garaitoa*,
>   que significa parte superior, estrecha y ahogada, qual es la garita.

(Es decir, lugar alto, estrecho y sin ventilación, como una garita.)

Además, el [*Origen del lenguaje y etimología castellana*](https://books.google.com/books?hl=es&id=vxMMAQAAIAAJ&dq=garito&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=garito) (1927), de Julio Cejador y Frauca, dice, en el fragmento que Google Books deja ver:

> *Gari-ta*, trigal, dió *garita* la choza, sin duda para cuidar los campos, garito.

Con lo cual la similitud vendría por el lado de "choza".

Pero por otra parte, el interesante libro *[Figures du jeu: Études lexico-semantiques sur le jeu de cartes en Espagne (XVIe - XVIIe siècle)](https://books.google.com/books?id=qeJCVlJg1FsC&pg=PA265&dq=garito&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=garito&f=false)*, pese a estar en francés, da algunas pistas:

> Corominas [autor del  *Diccionario crítico etimológico de la lengua
>   castellana*] hace derivar la palabra *garito* de *garita* (la cual
>   proviene del francés *guérite*, donde ha conservado el sentido),
>   derivación que se explica por el parecido de "la guarida de los
>   tahures" con "el escondite del soldado".

Y más adelante señala que el autor del siglo XVII Francisco Luque Fajardo no usó el término *garito* pero sí *garitero* ("tablajero [dueño de casa de juego] de casa pequeña y gente miserable") haciéndolo provenir de *garita*: según él, unos "estrechos aposentillos de galera", interpretación que parece no fue compartida por ningún lexicógrafo.

En conclusión, supongo que habrá que tomar como mayor autoridad a Corominas, cuya etimología es la que menciona el Diccionario de la RAE, mientras que las etimologías vascas y la de Luque Fajardo son curiosidades; y la tranformación de garita en garito obedecería entonces a lo que el primero menciona: el parecido entre "el escondite del soldado" con "la guarida de los tahúres". Tal vez alguien que tenga acceso a alguna edición del diccionario de Corominas pueda citar la entrada relevante.

Comment: ¡Fantástica explicación! Intentaré hacerme con el diccionario de Corominas para seguir leyendo sobre esta y tantas otras etimologías. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Una respuesta impresionante. Así da gusto :-)

Answer (score 0):

Garita, es una torrecilla con troneras que defiende a los centinelas de guardia en las fortificaciones o delante de cualquier edificio vigilado. La palabra viene del francés 'guárite', forma actual de 'garite' que procedía del provenzal 'garida'.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta y bienvenido al sitio! Su versión actual, si bien contiene información interesante, no responde a la pregunta. Considera editarla añadiendo más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

> La palabra **antro** viene del latín *antrum,* que en latín no
>   sólo significa gruta, caverna, sino también las cavidades en los
>   troncos de los árboles y empleado en plural, *antra,* se refiere
>   a las fosas nasales y a otras cavidades corporales.
>
> El latín tomó en préstamo el vocablo del griego (antron = cueva). En
>   castellano, no sólo se refiere a una [caverna](/?caverna)
>   sino a cualquier establecimiento oscuro, repelente y de mala
>   reputación.
>
> En medicina, la palabra **antro** se usa para indicar una cavidad
>   como la que tenemos dentro de los huesos.
>
> De unos años a la fecha, en México se utiliza esta palabra para
>   sustituir a disco discotheque está muy en boga ir los fines de semana
>   a los antros; es decir que ahora los antros ya no son de mala
>   reputación en México.

***Fuente:*** [Antro etomologia](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?antro)

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, Lobo-Eze. Nótese que aquí estoy preguntando por el origen de "garito". Si mencionaba "antro" en la pregunta es por la similaridad del término, pero esta respuesta seguramente pertenece más a esa otra pregunta: [¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra 'antro'?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3148/1674)